# How can I stop the guest user from running applications and accessing settings

Tags: windows-xp

I have a friend that owns a cafe that has some public computers and he asked if I knew how to stop the guest account from running applications and accessing control panel and hide the hard drive.

Is there an application I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Group Policy for this. To open it, open run (<kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and type `gpedit.msc`.

You can then edit settings related to users or on a system wide level. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307882) will get you started.

---

Alternatively if you want something easier to use, you can use Windows SteadyState. However I'm yet to find a download link (I've found a few, but not from reputable sources) as Microsoft axed the application on Dec 31, 2010.

**Update:** Download link is [here](http://download.cnet.com/Windows-SteadyState/3000-18512_4-11127965.html). Click `Direct download link` (its below the large green download button) if you'd rather not install CNet's download application.